# Error creating SSIS Service Catalog

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis

I installed a fresh `AZURE` machine with the latest `SQL Server` 2016 release. After having the issues running `ssis packages` (Exception deserializing the package...) I also cannot create a `ssis` service catalog. I'm getting the error:

> Method not found: 'Void.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.EnableSSISSupportAlwaysOnSqmHelper.Initialise()'

[image: Error creating SSIS Service Catalog Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

First enable clr using the following sql script:

sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO

Then create catalog using this powershell script:

## Load the IntegrationServices Assembly

## Store the IntegrationServices Assembly namespace to avoid typing it every time

$ISNamespace = "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices"

Write-Host "Connecting to server ..."

## Create a connection to the server

$sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $sqlConnectionString

Write-Host "Connected ..."

## Create the Integration Services object

$integrationServices = New-Object $ISNamespace".IntegrationServices" $sqlConnection

Write-Host "SSIS obj created ..."

## Provision a new SSIS Catalog

$catalog = New-Object $ISNamespace".Catalog" ($integrationServices, "SSISDB", "P@assword1")
$catalog.Create()